# Class that calls initiates the validation of itself and then initiates the assignment of offers

Tags: c#, ddd

Please see the code below:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int _iD { get; set; }
    public decimal _salary { get; set; }
    public List<String>_assignedOffers { get; set;  }
    private AbstractValidator<Customer> _validator;
    private IRulesOfferCalculator _rulesOfferCalculator;

    public Customer(AbstractValidator<Customer> validator, IRulesOfferCalculator rulesOfferCalculator)
    {
        _validator = validator;
        _rulesOfferCalculator = rulesOfferCalculator;
    }

    public void AssignOffers()
    {
        ValidationResult results = _validator.Validate(this);
        if (results.IsValid)
        {
            _assignedOffers = _rulesOfferCalculator.CalculateOffers(this);
        }
        else
        {
            _validator.ValidateAndThrow(this);
        }
    }
}
```

It is a Domain Layer class in a rich domain model.  I have used [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CreatingAValidator) for the validation. The Service Layer (WFC) creates an instance of Customer and initialises it.

The concern I have is that the class has two responsibilities:

1. Validate the customer.  If validation fails then thrown an exception.  Validation can fail if the customer is under 21 years old etc
2. If validation fails then throw an exception with reason for failure in the exception string.  If validation is successful then assign offers (`_assignedOffers`  is an instance variable)

I have two questions:

1. Is it bad practice to throw an exception if validation fails? Is there a better way to notify the user if validation fails?
2. Does this class have too many responsibilities i.e.

   1. validate and
   2. assign offers.

Alternatively the Service Layer could call: Validate and then call `AssignOffers` if `Validate` is successful.  However, I believe this would make the domain model anemic.

Please be aware that I am building a rich domain model.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it bad practice to throw an exception if validation fails? Is there a better way to notify the user if validation fails?

It depends but usually validations return some kind of a validation result.

---

> Does this class have too many responsibilities i.e. validate and assign offers.

Actually not. They are not the responsibilities of this class. Validation is injected and provided via a service so it's fine.

I would worry more about its design.

The constructor requries two parameters but their corresponding properties are not `readonly` so you could just use them. More appropriate would to use fields or make the properties `get` only and private.

---

> ```
> public void AssignOffers()
> {
>     ValidationResult results = _validator.Validate(this);
>     if (results.IsValid)
>     {
>         _assignedOffers = _rulesOfferCalculator.CalculateOffers(this);
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         _validator.ValidateAndThrow(this);
>     }
> }
> ```

It's a weird process. It first validates the object and then calculate the offer. The `Offer` property should be a getter-only property and use the calculator to get the value and the validation should take place where the other properties necessary for the calculation are set because they need to be validated as apparently they can be invalid.

Comment: Thanks.  I have made some changes to the code in the OP.  Could you take a look? Salary and DateOfBirth are still public because they are used by the validator i.e. a Person as to be over 21 years old etc.  Does it make more sense now?

Comment: @w0051977 you are not allowed to modify the code. Please roll it back and refer to: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @w0051977 otherwise someone else or I will roll it back anyway ;-]

Comment: @ t3chb0t, thanks for the warning.  I will roll it back now.

Comment: I have done that.  I will reread your link about the rules of this site.  Thanks.

Comment: If dateofbirth and salary are initialised in the constructor then would you still call the process weird? The validation ensures that the person is 21 or above.  I will change all of the instance variables so they are private and read only (except for dateofbirth, which is used by the validator).  Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 I can't rally comment on that as I don't know how this type is really used but I can give you a general advice. If the you set those fields only once then yes, it might be better to set them via the constructor. Immutable object are usually easier to work with. If however this type is bound to some UI control and may be updated frequently then properties are of course more appropriate.

Comment: It is a domain layer class in a rich domain model so it should not be bound to the ui or anything else.  I am asking if it is "bad" for this person class (person is an entity in the db) to do validation and assign offers.  I guess it is ok? Thanks again.

Comment: I have asked part two of this question in case you are interested: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166776/class-that-calls-initiates-the-validation-of-itself-and-then-initiates-the-assig

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CreatingAValidator) says, that the methods `Validate` and `ValidateAndThrow` are different ways to use the validator.

Therefore it is not required to use both. Something like the following should work just fine:

```
public void AssignOffers()
{
    _validator.ValidateAndThrow(this);
    _assignedOffers = _rulesOfferCalculator.CalculateOffers(this);
}
```

---

> Does this class have too many responsibilities

Actually, I am a fan of small and stupid domain models. Why should the domain model have a dependency to the validator and the calculator? How do you handle e.g. validations that require more than one domain model? All that stuff can IMHO be done in the controller, view model, whatever....

But that is only my personal preference. If you decide using rich domain models, I think that is OK because the actual validation / calculation logic is abstracted as t3chbot already mentioned.

---

> Is it bad practice to throw an exception if validation fails?

It depends. I would say, if validation failure is a common use case (e.g. validating user input), it would be better to use an validation approach without exceptions.

Otherwise, if validation failure is not expected (e.g. re-validating input from the client on the server), throwing an exception would be OK.

> Is there a better way to notify the user if validation fails?

Hopefully you catch the validation exception and handle it because unhandled exceptions are not an appropriated way to notify the use about validation errors ;)

Comment: Thanks.  How would I inform the user when a validation failure has occurred.  Can you post some code? Thanks again.

Comment: @w0051977: That depends on the context where `AssignOffers()`is called. You could show a message box or a validation message somewhere on the GUI....

Comment: Thanks.  The Person class is called from a service layer.  The service layer is called by a few clients i.e. WPF, MVC4 and mobile.  AssignOffers is called by the service layer.

Comment: @w0051977: That discussion is out of scope of the code review. For conceptual questions [softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) is the right place.